# Android Data Binding: Is there a good way to show / hide an includes tag?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have just begun to mess around with data binding in android. Ideally I would like to have a root xml file that contains some generic xml elements and then its inner contents can be one of three xml files something like this

```
<data>
  <variable name="action" type="com.example.android.action"/>
</data>

<TextView>
<TextView>
<!--Only show one of these includes based on the binding data-->

<!-- if action.item -->
<include layout="item.xml"
 bind:item="@{action.item}">

<!-- else if action.udpate -->
<include layout="update.xml"
 bind:update="@{action.update}">

<!-- else if action.video -->
<include layout="video.xml"
 bind:video="@{action.video}">

<TextView>
... etc
```

So basically based on what child object exists inside of action (either item, update or video) show the layout for it and bind the view but do not show the other includes. Should I just use android's `View:Visibility` or is there something with includes that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Should I just use android's View:Visibility

Yes, best approach is checking `boolean` in data binding layout and set visibility accordingly like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="action"
            type="com.example.android.action"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/item"
            android:visibility="@{action.item ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/update"
            android:visibility="@{action.someOtherObject!=null ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Here you can check `NULL` or `Boolean` as above.

Comment: But what if I want to make the visibility based on multiple conditions: say if(obj != null && !(obj.getText().toString.isEmpty)):
ie. how to achieve this:



if(TextUtils.isEmpty(action.textData))
VISIBILITY = GONE;
else
VISIBILITY = VISIBLE;

Answer (score 0):

Remember to give the included layout an `id` else it won't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
            name="show"
            type="Boolean" />
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:background="@color/colorPrimary">


        <include layout="@layout/progress"
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:visibility="@{show?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(action.textData)) VISIBILITY = GONE; else VISIBILITY = VISIBLE;
```

You can import TextUtils in data tag and then use the TextUtils isEmpty() function in the xml file